# Resque - rake aborts

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake, resque, rake-task, rakefile

Iam new to ruby on rails, currently iam trying to make my task to run at background using resque gem

I had installed redis and resque gem successfully, Now i want to run my rake file which is placed at .../lib/tasks/resque.rake

### content in resque.rake

require 'resque/tasks'

task "resque:setup" => :environment

---

I had started my redis server, Opened a new terminal and moved to my app path now i executed the rake command which is

rake resque:work QUEUE='*'

Now i got an error as

rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'resque:work'
.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in`'

Please help me to fix the bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following to start the rake task,

```
QUEUE=* VVERBOSE=1 rake environment resque:work
```

From here,

http://bradhe.wordpress.com/2011/05/09/notes-on-working-with-resque-in-rails-3and-ruby-1-8/